# three.js project in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, three.js

I have a project based on three.js. It works properly on Chrome browser on dekstops and on mobiles.
It also works properly in webview in Lollipop version.
However it throws the following error in Kitkat version (from logcat)-

```
[ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(5758)] [.SharedGraphicsContext.WebGLRenderingContext.WebGLRenderingContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'
```

[The final rendered scene I get is all black.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCahy.jpg)

Please help me to understand this error.
I would appreciate any guidelines on how to debug and fix this.

Comment: I am not running on emulator but on actual device.
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview says that new WebView for Kitkat is based on Chrome for Android version number 30.
My project runs correctly on Chrome for Android on Kitkat but not on WebView on Kitkat.

Comment: WebGL isn't supported in KitKat WebView as it is version 33. WebView versions didn't more or less sync up with Chrome until Lollipop (5.x) and the 'Android System WebView'. The key part of the page you linked to is: `Chrome for Android supports a few features which aren't enabled in the WebView, including:` So it wasn't until WebView 36 that gets WebGL.

Comment: Ok I missed that part somehow. Thank you for highlighting it!

Comment: I've also updated my answer on the other question to include another possible path.

Comment: Thank you for the edit on the other question, Crosswalk seems very promising!